# Reduce a Collection List to single value Unit

Tags: list, scala, reduce

I have to a value of Type `List[Unit]` what can I do to reduce it to `Unit` instead?

```
 def insertMany(users: List[User]) : IO[Unit] =
    lines.map(line => createorUpdate(user))
      .transact(xa)


def createorUpdate(user: User): ConnectionIO[Unit] =
    sql"""
          INSERT INTO $tableName ($columns)
          VALUES (${user.id}, ${user.age}, NOW(), NOW())
          ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING"""
      .update.run
      .map(_ => ())
```

Here is the complete definition
I'm getting as an error :

```
value transact is not a member of List[doobie.ConnectionIO[Unit]]
                       [error] possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value transact'?
                       [error]       .transact(xa)
                       [error]        ^
                       [error] one error found
```

Comment: Just throw it away and return `Unit`? There is only 1 unit value, so there's no need to do anything with the list.

Comment: Unless you need to perform some side effect for each element of your list though. Then you do `list.foreach(_ => /* some side effect */)`

Comment: how can  I throw away the list ?

Comment: Why do you even want to do it? How are you getting list of unit in the first place, it's not good practice to use Unit as a return type. That's the whole point of having a strictly type language.

Comment: at the end I am getting IO[List[Unit]] it is safe but I don't need the list using

Comment: .transact of doobie is not defined for Unit that's why

Comment: You can use `ioList.void` to throw the units out; though maybe you should've done it earlier - like used `.compile.drain` if you're working with fs2.Stream instead of `.compile.toList`

Comment: can you add an example? I am going to guess you need either `sequence` or `traverse_` since you are talking about doobie with IOs

Comment: @roundcrisis I have added the full definition for more details

Comment: @OlegPyzhcov can you check the question I have edited it with more explicit example

Comment: @AM try replacing the first `map` with `traverse_` and also the `.map(_ => ())` with `.void` - Also, if you are new to FP in **Scala**, it may be good to read the book _"Scala with Cats"_ and related resources like the **cats-effect** documentation.

Comment: the second method can be reused for adding multiple users as well as a single user

Comment: you mean like : .traverse(line => createOrUpdateHelper(user)) instead of map(line => createOrUpdateHelper(line)) ??

Comment: @AM yeah but `traverse_` note the underscore at the end. Also, you can just pass the method directly: `lines.traverse_(lcreateorUpdate).transact(xa)`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez can you add it as an answer so that I can accept it ? thanks

Comment: @AM roundcrisis already did ;)

Comment: Why don't you use `insertMany`? What is the database that you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for `[updateMany][1]` tho there are times when that just doesn't work.

If you are trying to make the code you have work, you need to apply `transact` to the IO

so it would have to be something like this :

```
def insertMany(lines: List[String]) : IO[Unit] =
    lines.map(line => createorUpdate(line)).sequence_.transact(xa)
```

`sequence` basically changes from List[IO[your_type]] to IO[List[your_type]]...

When you have `map` and then `sequence_` you can always  convert to `traverse` so this would work too

```
def insertMany(lines: List[String]) : IO[Unit] =
  lines.traverse_(line => createorUpdate(line)).transact(xa)
```